# How to merge comma seperated keys of an array to value of another array and make a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
Array-1
    (
        [0] => title,size
        [1] => color
        [2] => length
    )

Array-2
    (
        [size_1] => 100
        [color_1] => 200
        [material_1] => 480
    )
```

I am trying to achieve the below array in php from above arrays.

```
Array
    (
        [title] => 100
        [size] => 100
        [color] => 200
        [length] => 480
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Savy, we don't see any size value in array two

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda, I have to merge keys of first array  and values of second array . PLease check I have given sample of output

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler approach is to loop and explode all values of first array and use array fill to create the values array.

```
$arr = array('title,size', 'color', 'length');
$b = array('size_1' => 100, 'color_1' => 200, 'material_1' => 480);
$b = array_values($b); // since we don't need the keys, just remove them

$result =[];
foreach($arr as $key => $a){
    $temp = explode(",", $a);
    $result = array_merge($result, array_combine($temp, array_fill(0, count($temp), $b[$key])));
}
var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/Q1mMu

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_combine` to create a new array where key will be taken from array1 and values from array2 then use `foreach` to iterate them both together and produce desired result like this:

```
<?php

$a = array('title,size', 'color', 'length');
$b = array('size_1' => 100, 'color_1' => 200, 'material_1' => 480);
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

$result = array();
foreach($c as $key => $val) {
    if(strpos($key, ',')) {
        $temp = explode(',', $key);
        foreach($temp as $keys){
            $result[$keys] = $val;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $val;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($c);
print_r($result);

/*
------------------
Output
------------------
$a = Array
(
    [0] => title,size
    [1] => color
    [2] => length
)
$b = Array
(
    [size_1] => 100
    [color_1] => 200
    [material_1] => 480
)
$c = Array
(
    [title,size] => 100
    [color] => 200
    [length] => 480
)
$result = Array
(
    [title] => 100
    [size] => 100
    [color] => 200
    [length] => 480
)
*/
?>
```